# Firebase Remote config fetch cache discrepancy 16.3.0 vs 16.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am experiencing an weird issue with the latest Android SDK **com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.3.0**

In my app's splash screen I use the fetch method like this

```
config.fetch(EXPIRY_CACHE).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            config.activateFetched()
                    }
```

where EXPIRY_CACHE = 3600L (1hour)

**Scenario:**
I open the app and I see some value for parameter X, after fetching for the first time.
Then From firebase console I update parameter's X value and publish the changes.
Then instantly I open the app and I see the new updated value immediately.

**Actual Result:**   RemoteConfig 1hour cache is not respected. - I see every updated value immediately without any cache waiting time

**Expected Result:** I should see the updated value of parameter X 1hour after since the last fetch.

On the other hand the exact same code works correctly satisfying the Expected Result when using an older version of the SDK **com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0**

Is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: We can specify time in `RemoteConfig` in `Firebase` ?

Comment: I'm seeing the change in behavior you describe from 16.0.0 to 16.3.0:  A published parameter value change is seen after the next calls to fetch/activate even when the cache is not expired.  For debug and testing my code uses [getInfo()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#public-method-summary) to log the fetch status and last fetch time.  Logs confirm that in 16.3.0, a fetch to the server is triggered by a published value change.  Suggest you contact Firebase Support.